# Node.js - Loop async

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, loops

I'm new to nodejs and trying to call a function inside of the for loop just to print something.

```
var mysql = require("mysql"),
    async = require("async");

function test() {

    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('boo');
    }, 100)
}

con.query('SELECT * FROM database', function(err, rows){
    if(err) throw err;

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log('Processing ID: ' + rows[i].id);
        test();
    }

});
```

It seems that the loop doesn't wait to boo appear to continue going thru all values. Here's the output:

```
Processing ID: 1
Processing ID: 2
boo
boo
```

But what i really want is this:

```
Processing ID: 1
boo
Processing ID: 2 
boo
```

I also tried using async library like this:

```
async.each(rows, function(rows, callback) {         
    console.log('Processing ID: ' + rows.id);
    test();
    callback();

}, function(err) {
    if( err ) {
        console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
        console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a .1 second delay on printing to the console with your `setTimeout` call. But even that may not fix things.

Comment: Is order important to your question?  async documentation explicitly states "
Note, that since this function applies iteratee to each item in parallel, there is no guarantee that the iteratee functions will complete in order."

Comment: @aaaaaa Not really. But this is a simple example just so i can understand the process. Because am using webdriver and: "driver.wait(until.elementLocated...". The for doesn't wait to the element to be located and continues the loop process.

Comment: Try async.each (see my answer)

Comment: who's downvoting all the answers? i'm still testing those..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` is async and doesn't block the rest of the code. It basically is saying "I will call `console.log('boo')` in 100ms, in the meantime just continue with the rest of the code".
This has to do with the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), which is really well explained in this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Using the async lib you could use [`eachSeries`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries)

```
async.eachSeries(
    rows,
    function(row, callback) {
      console.log('Processing ID: ' + row.id)
      setTimeout(function() { 
          console.log('boo')
          callback()
      }, 100)
    },
    function(){
        // is called when done
    }
)
```

`eachSeries` will wait with each iteration until the callback is called. And since `setTimeout` is async, you need to call the callback there.

Working JSBin:
https://jsbin.com/gequduhoma/1/edit?js,console

Comment: he didn't ask why output is coming like this.

Comment: @Mahi he did: "But this is a simple example just so i can understand the process."

Comment: @ziad.ali sorry, my mistake, it was `eachSeries`

Comment: @Moezalez that worked! Thank you. Does every 'callback();' means next itineration of the loop? If i want to know when the for each is over that i can call 'connection.end()' what i do? is there a function to do that?

Comment: yes, when callback is called the next iteration starts. When it's done, the last callback is called. See http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries

Answer (score 0):

## The following is how you'd go about your problem

```
const async = require('async');
const processingIds = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3'];

function test(aProcessingId, done) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('Processing ID: ' + aProcessingId);
    console.log('boo');
    done();
  }, 100);
}

function iteratee(aProcessingId, done) {
  test(aProcessingId, done);
}

async.each(processingIds, iteratee);
```

which prints

```
Processing ID: a1
boo
Processing ID: b2
boo
Processing ID: c3
boo
```

## The problem with your code:

```
async.each(rows, function(rows, callback) {         
  console.log('Processing ID: ' + rows.id); // #1
  test(); // #2
  callback();
```

#1 - `async.each` fires immediately for all your rows, which is why console.log is firing immediately for all your processing ids.

#2 - `test()` starts a new async function that says "in 0.1 seconds, type "boo", which executes once per list item.  So 0.1 seconds after all the process ids are printed, `boo`'s appear